# MYSQL: Getting the second last max value row, but some date not showing. Why?

Tags: mysql

With this query (subsection of a much larger query):

```
-- Get second last transaction per item
select max(i.transaction), item
from (
    -- Rows not including max transaction
    select item, transaction
    from positivetest.history_items
    where transaction not in (
        -- Max transaction per item
        select max(transaction) 
        from positivetest.history_items
        group by item
        )
    ) i
group by item
```

and the following (relevant) data. (I am trimming the data from my real database for simplicity, for example item 0 really has 16 entries):

| transaction | item |
| --- | --- |
| 294474 | 0 |
| 294474 | 0 |
| 715439 | 0 |
| 1299009 | 0 |
| 119427 | 1 |
| 137450 | 1 |
| 177632 | 3 |
| 325260 | 3 |
| 669580 | 3 |
| 871509 | 3 |
| 951363 | 3 |
| 539784 | 4 |
| 845808 | 4 |
| 468110 | 5 |
| 965661 | 5 |
| 1326575 | 5 |
| 1327567 | 5 |

Gives the result:

| max(i.transaction) | item |
| --- | --- |
| 715439 | 0 |
| 119427 | 1 |
| 871509 | 3 |
| 726859 | 5 |

Item 4 does not show here as it should. It should have the transaction 539784.

Running the inner most select (Max transaction per item) I get:

| max(transaction) | item(not actually in resulting data table) |
| --- | --- |
| 1299009 | 0 |
| 137450 | 1 |
| 951363 | 3 |
| 845808 | 4 |
| 1327567 | 5 |

Item 4 is showing and the correct max transactions per item.

The next select (Rows not including max transaction) is where 4 does not show along with some values that should be, including some from 3 and 5:

| item | transaction |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 294474 |
| 0 | 294474 |
| 0 | 715439 |
| 1 | 119427 |
| 3 | 177632 |
| 3 | 669580 |
| 3 | 871509 |
| 5 | 468110 |

I am confused as to why the correct data is not showing. I expect all but the max transaction per item should be showing after this point. The Final select should be the second largest transaction per item, but since some data is missing, this is not correct. 4 is missing all together.

Does it have to do something with the execution order of the query? or am I not understanding it correctly?

My goal is to get the second largest transaction per item. Perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by item order by transaction desc) as rn
  from positivetest.history_items
) x
where rn = 2 -- filtering the second one, using descending order
```